# Make different programs output to different soundcards

Tags: windows, audio, sound-card, amplification

I want to upgrade my "computer room" a bit by buying an amplifier and a pair of speakers so everybody in the room can listen on music from my computer. 
But at the same time I want to play some games on the computer (a laptop) and listen to the sound from the game through my headphones.

Is this possible?

I have read many forums but couldn't find an answer for me.

I thought that maybe I could connect the headphones to my 3.5 mm jack and then buy a external sound card and connect that with USB to the laptop and then connect the amplifier to the soundcard.

Will that work?

Comment: Might be possible. Games will probably use your default soundcard but if you use a music/media player that allows you to specify which device to use then it might work.

Answer (score 0):

No need to buy additional audio card just for music. You can use audio player with channels redirect capabilities instead. So that your game can be configured to use only 2 front channels (for headphones) and audio player can be configured to use rear 2 channels for amplifier. A good example is foobar2000 audio player with foo_channel_mixer DSP plugin (among other things, it can redirect channels in whatever way you like), which can be downloaded [here](http://skipyrich.com/wiki/Foobar2000:Channel_Mixer). Note that plugin is a little bit dated, so you will have to repack it's dll into zip archive and rename it to have .fb2k-component extension (instead of zip), so that recent versions of foobar2000 could install it.

Comment: Will I be able to play music via Spotify then?

Comment: I believe you will not.